# DRUPAL problems

Tags: drupal

I am having problem installing Drupal; I usually use Wampserver or Acquia, but the problem is they do not work for a long time. Whenever I install Drupal, the next day it won't work.

Is there any other software I can use, aside from Wampserver and Acquia?

Comment: "the next day they won't work" ... kind of hard to troubleshoot without more details here

Comment: sorry, what I mean is how to install drupal. I used local host for installing drupal, is there any way I can install drupal without a problem?

Comment: 1. Installing a Local Web Server - https://www.drupal.org/node/159534 
2. Installation Guide - https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specific enough so it will be impossible to address your issue, there are a lot of tutorials online, go to drupal.org and find the resources for beginners.

Also you need to have some form of idea of how a local server works, you don't really need to go into details, start to understand the general workflow of a PHP application such as Drupal. Find tutorials about basic PHP, local servers etc...

It doesn't seem that your problem is Drupal related by the way. Not working the next day would seem to point to your local server settings, something as basic as not starting it for instance.

Comment: What I mean is how to install drupal, by the way I am talking about the wampserver that I use which really gave me a hard time to create my drupal site

Comment: Installing Drupal is pretty straightforward actually, there's really not much to it :) So I guess your problem is really your understanding of the Wamp server. My advice is for you to close this question, and look into your Wamp server settings...

Comment: I have been using wampserver but the problem is that it is not reliable. I don't know but it won't work. I have already installed 32 bits as it coincides with my computer but still it doesn't work

Comment: Can't help you with Wamp, I'm on Mac, but you should ask a new question regarding Wamp installation issues

Comment: okay, that will be fine, is mac a loca lhost? I have another quwstion how can we make this online if we are using local host so that other people may see your site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be clear on what problem you are facing? what u mean by not working?? basically both of them are bundled software apache+mysql+php pre-configured for small site.. 
Can you please tell little more about your drupal instance like..
Site traffic, server configuration..

If u feel it has slown down.. check ur MySQL, PHP and Apache Configuration..

Comment: thanks for the response, what I mean is that I have problem installing drupal on my computer. I used local host like wampserver and acquia. what I wan is someone who can advise me what to do or what other techniques is best. I am new to drupal by the way

Comment: As you are new to drupal.. you can start experimenting with WAMP..  guess u require little knowledge about basic networking.. browse on the basics...  localhost is just a proxy for 127.0.0.1 thats like talking locally to ur wamp... if u put ur WAMP online.. your site will be available for people in network.. during constrution keep it  in offline so its only available locally..

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding... when u start the wampmanager, u can find the wamp icon in ur taskbar tray... click on it and choose the bottom most option, put online and then u can use ur system's ip address instead of localhost.. let me know if is there anything i can help...

Comment: can anyone access it when I 'm using a localhost? for example I want people to see my site and I gave them the link on local, can they see it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will use the XAMP from (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) . It is a lot more stable than WAMP.

- First install the XAMP on your computer (It will take care of all the PHP, MySQL, Apache, and PHPMyAdmin installation)
- Go to the XAMP interface on your browser, http://localhost
- Go to the PHPMyAdmin interface
- Create username, password, and database through PHPMyAdmin Interface
- Then Go to Drupal.org and download the latest Drupal installation package.
- Unzip the Drupal to the XAMP htdocs folder
- Install Drupal with the database name and user name that you created
- and you are done! you can go to starbucks, buy coffee and watch netflix now :)

Answer (score 0):

Other options to consider are VirtualBox, [Lando](https://docs.devwithlando.io/), & Docker Desktop.